# Highcharts: Preprocess data using CSV

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

Hello I am getting started with Highcharts for Datajournalism and I am trying to load data from a CSV file as described in the documentation 'processing data from a file' (http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json)

However, the only thing I get is a blank page and this error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/.../data.csv. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

My file data.csv is in the same folder as the script highcharts_2.html itself. The folder 'js' that is contained in the Highcharts download is also in the same folder as the data and the script. Below is the highchart_2.html I used...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!--where you put the high charts library -->

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit Consumption'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Units'
                    }
                },
                series: []
            };


            $.get('data.csv', function(data) {
                // Split the lines
                var lines = data.split('\n');
                $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                    var items = line.split(',');

                    // header line containes categories
                    if (lineNo == 0) {
                        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                            if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                        });
                    }

                    // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
                    else {
                        var series = { 
                            data: []
                        };
                        $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                            if (itemNo == 0) {
                                series.name = item;
                            } else {
                                series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                            }
                        });         
                        options.series.push(series);
                    }   
                }); 
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });


</script>




<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

I searched all forums already and just look at the html and think it should be working but it doesn't. I am pretty sure it will be a 'facepalm' but I just can't find the solution. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Something's fishy about the error code, double check the location of the ../../data.csv reference vs. data.csv in the code you are testing. Also, what is the URL you are using, the assumption is that you are locally running this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load file from webserver, not from local filesystem. The browsers block this scenario.

Comment: Sorry for coming back so late (I was offline the last couple days) - the webserver was exactly the problem! Thank you very much Sebstian! I tried on my website, it works now - will install a local webserver to test offline, too. Great!